# Does disintegrating perlite produce clay?

Tags: watering, soil, soil-amendment, perlite

Perlite sand is extremely fine. Is it clay? Will it cake up my soil over a long period of time(e.g.10 years)?

Comment: I am familiar with perlite but not perlite sand, can you add a picture with something to show the size of the particles?

Comment: Clay is not composed of simply very fine particles.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean perlite, no, it's not clay and doesn't turn into clay, it is made from expanded volcanic glass, see here https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/what-is-perlite/